# Doing constraint-satisfaction in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, constraints

Say that I have a number of users, each of which has a set of numbers between `0` and `n`. For example, one user may have a set `{3, 7}`, another might have `{7, 8, 9}`, etc.

I want to get the smallest number of users, that if I take a union of all their sets, I'll get the set of all numbers between `0` and `n`.

Bonus points if you come up with a way that also lets me assign a variable price to each user (instead of using `1` like above) so the algorithm would find the combination of users with the minimum total price.

I've seen packages that deal with constraint-satisfaction in Python ([like this one](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/constraint/0.4.1)) but I have no idea how to use them. If they can be used for this, great.

Comment: Looks like a hard problem. I take it brute-forcing is out of the question?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

Comment: It is indeed set cover, so there is probably no polynomial-time solution. You could use an exponential dynamic program or formulate the problem as an [ILP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) and use a generic solver for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an solution for [PuLP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP)/[GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/). I've never used PuLP before, but it's on PyPI and seems to do the job. GLPK is pretty good and free.

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
from pulp import *


User = namedtuple('User', ('coverage', 'price'))


def solvesetcover(users):
    vars = [LpVariable('x{}'.format(i), 0, 1, cat='Binary') for i, user in enumerate(users)]
    prob = LpProblem()
    totals = defaultdict(int)
    for user, var in zip(users, vars):
        prob += user.price * var
        for elt in user.coverage:
            totals[elt] += var
    for total in totals.values():
        prob += total >= 1
    GLPK(msg=0).solve(prob)
    return [user for user, var in zip(users, vars) if value(var)]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    users = []
    users.append(User({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 1.16))
    users.append(User({8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 1.08))
    users.append(User({1, 8}, 1.04))
    users.append(User({2, 3, 9, 10}, 1.02))
    users.append(User({4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14}, 1.01))
    print(solvesetcover(users))
```